# authentication in spring boot using graphql

Tags: authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, graphql, graphql-java

I’m working on a spring boot project with GraphQL. I'm using graphql-java-tools and graphql-spring-boot-starter. I managed to configure security and session management with spring security as you can see in the java config files below.

Now the “/graphql” path is secured (it can be accessed only sending the “basic http authentication” or a session token (`x-auth-token`) in a http header of the request). Authenticating with “basic http authentication” on any GraphQL operation will start a new session and send back the new session token in a header, and that token can be used further to continue that session.

How to give access to anonymous users to some GraphQL queries/mutations keeping the above behavior?

If I change `antMatchers("/graphql").authenticated()` to `antMatchers("/graphql").permitAll()` in order to allow anonymous access, then my custom `AuthenticationProvider` is not called anymore even when I try to authenticate with “basic http authentication”.

Thanks!

Here are my configs:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/graphql").authenticated()
            .and()
            .requestCache()
            .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin() // needed for H2 web console
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

```java
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 180)
public class HttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `.antMatchers("/graphql").authenticated()` we used `.antMatchers("/graphql").permitAll()`, then we removed `.httpBasic()` and also removed the custom `AuthenticationProvider`. Now the security configs look like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/graphql").permitAll()
            .and()
            .requestCache()
            .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin() // needed for H2 web console
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

Then we created a mutation for login that accepts the user's credentials and returns the session token. Here is the graphql schema:

```
login(credentials: CredentialsInputDto!): String

input CredentialsInputDto {
    username: String!
    password: String!
}
```

Basically the code we had in our custom AuthenticationProvider went into the service that is called by the login operation:

```java
public String login(CredentialsInputDto credentials) {
    String username = credentials.getUsername();
    String password = credentials.getPassword();

    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

    ... credential checks and third party authentication ...

    Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    httpSession.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
    return httpSession.getId();
}
```

The key is that we prepared the session context with the authenticated user's authentication and then we save it (in redis) as a session attribute called "SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT". This is all what spring needs to be able to automatically restore the context when you make a request having the "x-auth-token" header set with the value of the session token obtained from the login operation.

Now also anonymous calls are allowed because of `.antMatchers("/graphql").permitAll()` and in the service layer, on public methods we can use annotations like this: `@Preauthorize("isAnonymous()` OR `hasRole("USER")")`.

Answer (score 11):

Even though you need to use `permitAll()` you can still create reasonable default for your resolver methods using AOP.

You can create your custom security aspect that will require authentication by default.

Unsecured methods may be marked for example using annotation.

See my blog post for details: https://michalgebauer.github.io/spring-graphql-security

Comment: Blog post assisted me tremendously regarding this issue, great work!

Comment: I just wanted to say I spent the whole day searching for a solution until I found your blog post, thanks a lot!